# Token supply and decimals / metamask

Tags: metamask

I recently created this token on mainnet. https://etherscan.io/address/0xef54d5a930fd31d4a9e8975ffd2522c295d4cc1c#code
It's total supply is 50,000,000 tokens, with 18 decimal places.

However, when i add token to metamask I see 50000000000000000000000000 (18 too many zeros) .

Have i done anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deployed the contract and the amount of tokens displays correctly on Metamask.

Did you set 18 decimals when adding the tokens on Metamask?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes i did.   I supposed you deployed it on Kovan right? It works fine on Kovan but not mainnet.

Comment: Deployed on Ropsten. There's no reason why it would display differently on mainnet... Could you transfer some of the tokens to this address on mainnet so I don't have to deploy a contract to see it? I'll check how it displays. 0x0e6803026c3B577f2be55d8D6998B9882461Ee83

Comment: ok you know what? I tried on another computer with metamask and it displayed correctly.